# Google Play In-App Purchasing Issue

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I added the "com.android.vending.BILLING" permission that all the docs and forums say to add to your AndroidManifest.xml file.  I uploaded a signed APK file to Google Play.  But, the section of the developer console for adding "in-app products" still says I need to upload an APK with the BILLING permission.  What is missing here?

Comment: make sure your package name does not contains "com.example.appname" because google will not allowed you to publish or access data from the package name contains this package name. you can simply change your package name.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied innappbillingservice file from sdk to your app:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h2ESH71hAI